# Bootstrap / Dropdown Button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Im trying to create a dropdown button using bootstrap. But it just doesnt seem to come out correctly ?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

A jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/UrgP8/

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems like a javascript problem: for starters you are including bootstrap-dropdown.js and bootstrap.min.js you should only need one, but that doesn't solve the problem in the fiddle...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are loading a hefty amount of external resources into jsfiddle by pasting what is practically the full boostrap html source into the html view.

Here is a much more bare-bones version 
that loads only three external files.

http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/65/

The base html is the same (SO wouldn't let me post without putting in code...)

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that jQuery is loaded via jsFiddle's Framework panel, 
bootstrap css and js are loaded via the [BootstrapCDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/):

//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

---

What happens if you save this html as a page, and run it in a browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Action
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems to be that they all work in jsfiddle but as soon as I try directly within a browser I get the same issue ?

Comment: @felix001 - not quite sure what you mean. I've pasted the code, with a few more items removed, that was in the jsfiddle. What happens when you run that in a browser?

Comment: Many Thanks, its now working I think it was how I was loading the js scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Ok found what seems to be the problem in your fiddle.

It's that you are loading:

```
<link href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I changed it to:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And that basically solved it.
You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6hPMb/1/

---

But besides that, the problem I mentioned in the comments still stands, you are loading both **bootstrap-dropdown.js** and **bootstrap.min.js**

You should only use one.